# Проблема с формативаронием строк

Tags: python

Вот мой код

```
grades = {"A": 5, "B": 5, "C": 4, "D": 3, "E": 3, "FX": 2, "F": 1}


def formatted_grades(students):
    b = []
    count = 1
    for i, y in students.items():
        if y in grades.keys():
            shit = "{}|{}|{}|{}".format(str(count).rjust(4), i.ljust(10), y.center(5), str(grades[y]).center(5))
        count += 1
        b.append(shit)
    return b


for el in formatted_grades({'Nick': 'A', 'Olga': 'B', 'Boris': 'FX', 'Anna': 'C'}):
    print(el)
```

```
   1|Nick      |  A  |  5
   2|Olga      |  B  |  5  - вот так так должно выводится
   3|Mike      | FX  |  2
   4|Anna      |  C  |  4

   1|Nick      |  A  |  5
   2|Olga      |  B  |  5
   3|Mike      |  FX |  2  - мой код выводит это
   4|Anna      |  C  |  4
```

Comment: 1) Исправьте отступы. 2) Приведите пример как вы хотите чтобы выглядел вывод.

Comment: исправил и привел пример

Comment: Гай, посмотрите, как правильно код включать (через `~~~` и с правильными отступами - я исправил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну сделайте через `rjust`, и добавьте пробелов сколько нужно справа:

```py
shit = "{}|{}|{} |{}".format(str(count).rjust(4), i.ljust(10), y.rjust(3), str(grades[y]).center(5))
                ^                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Альтернативный вариант, если нужно оставить `center` обязательно:

```py
shit = "{}|{}|{}|{}".format(str(count).rjust(4), i.ljust(10), (y + ' '*(len(y) - 1)).center(5), str(grades[y]).center(5))
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: делал,но нужно именно с такими значениями выравнивания

Comment: Добавил ещё вариант

Answer (score 0):

'*<*'   Символы-заполнители будут справа (выравнивание объекта по левому краю) (по умолчанию).
'*>*'   выравнивание объекта по правому краю.
'*=*'   Заполнитель будет после знака, но перед цифрами. Работает только с числовыми типами.
'*^*'   Выравнивание по центру.

Comment: слушай мой ответ тебе помог или же сделать изменение в твоем коде?